# Typescript folders base absolute imports

Tags: reactjs, typescript

At my company we like to organize our React code like this:

```
components/
    button.tsx
    slider.tsx
    index.ts
helpers/
    math.ts
    auth.ts
    index.ts
constants/
    config.ts
    api.ts
    index.ts
```

Where each `index.ts` exports all its adjacent files. Then everything is imported from the folders like this:

```
// I am button.tsx
import { login, sum } from '../helpers';
import { API_KEY } from '../constants';
import { Slider } from './slider';
```

I will want to instead look like this:

```
import { login, sum } from 'helpers';
import { API_KEY } from 'constants';
import { Slider } from 'components';
```

I messed around with absolute import settings in `tsconfig.json` but I didn't make it work.

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: you need the `baseUrl` and `paths` properties in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need add bellow lines in your `tsonfig.json` file (in your project root):

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
```

Comment: Ohh! It was as simple as this. I did follow too complicated steps. Thank you!